# Paper jam on laser printer

Tags: printing, printer, paper, paper-tray

I have a [Samsung SCX-4623F](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/SCX-4623F/XSS) that takes two paper sheets at time.

What happens is that if I insert just one sheet in the tray it takes that sheet correctly and prints out everything.

When I put more than one sheet in the tray, the printer takes a sheet, then when half of the sheet is picked up it picks up another sheet. That way the printer stops working and I have to manually remove the paper from it.

I already ordered [a new pick up roller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FCDPZ0) and replaced it but the problem persists.

What should I do next? What can cause this issue?

Comment: Change your paper stock.

Comment: @Tetsujin What do you mean? It's a stock that works perfectly with every other printer I have (I currently have one inkjet printer and another laser printer), so I don't think it's the problem...

Comment: [sorry, was adding info to a rapid comment]… or at least flip it over & properly get some air in it before stacking in the tray. Put index fingers under both nearest corners; lift your fingers *without* holding the sheets, just make the corners bend up; then grip. Take your grip back down to 'level' with the stack. Lift the stack & slap on a flat surface gently. Note how every sheet is marginally air-gapped from all the others except for your held corners. Place the sheets back in the tray; gently smooth that air out again. Also, moisture content in the paper can affect pickup.

Comment: BTW, this is not from a computer perspective - I spent years in the printing industry ;-)

Comment: Ok, I tried what you said but the problem persists... I have also just opened the printer to see if there was some piece of broken paper in there but it seems to be clean...

Comment: ah, OK, sorry. I have a different Samsung, older, which sometimes displays the same symptom, but I've never known it persist beyond a quick paper rejig. Hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Is the printer set for **thick stock**, i.e. 90 to 105 g/m 2 (24 to 28 lb) or envelopes? If so, adjust it; see p.48 of the [manual](http://www.expressautomation.com/Portals/2/app_images/pdf/Samsung_SCX-4623F.pdf). See *troubleshooting* on p. 91 and 98, also.
2. Does the the feed mechanism need cleaning? Rubber parts may become glazed or coated with paper dust. Follow cleaning instructions in the manual, at [Samsung's support](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00039061/700520654/SCX-4623F/XAA) and the [PrinterQuestions](http://printersquestions.com/Samsung-SCX-4623F-Printer-won-t-take-the-paper.html) site.

My experience on other printers has been been that **carefully** cleaning feed rollers with alcohol helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try as soon as I get the new toner, without changing it the printer won't let me edit its settings :/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue and I get to this topic first, finally I have fixed it following this guy's guide:

https://mypcjobs.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/samsung-scx-4623f-solenoid-issues/

The guide mentions three potential problems: faulty pickup roller, faulty separation pad or faulty solenoid.  In that author's case, the problem was a sticky solenoid.

The solution requires getting a [service manual](https://elektrotanya.com/samsung_scx-4600_scx-4623f.pdf/download.html), which describes how to disassemble the printer to access the solenoid and test it.

The issue was a degraded sponge in the solenoid that became sticky instead of springy.  Replacing that solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same printer with the exact same problem. I tried different paper, different humidity, replaced all kinds of rubber parts, etc. to no avail. I fixed it yesterday by following the [link](https://mypcjobs.wordpress.com/2017/01/10/samsung-scx-4623f-solenoid-issues/) in user3269930's answer. I'm writing the steps here in case the link goes down.

The problem is that one or two solenoids that control the paper feed mechanism are sticking. The foam pads on the solenoids get sticky over time. To fix them, you must disassemble the printer.

1. Unplug the printer. Press the power button to attempt to drain the capacitors (can't hurt).
2. Remove the front door and paper tray.
3. Remove 5 screws and the cover from the power supply on the back.
4. Remove the left side of the printer. There are hooks/clips along the bottom, sides, and top. Remove the bottom and sides first, then push up firmly to unclip the top.
5. Remove the plastic cover from the fax lines (1 screw and some clips).
6. Remove the motherboard (lots of plugs and 4 screws).
7. Remove the metal plate the motherboard was mounted on (4 screws).
8. Remove the drive unit (6 screws). You can leave it plugged in.
9. Remove the triangular, metal plate covering the paper feed gears and solenoids. Maybe take a photo/sketch of the solenoids so you can get them back in correctly.
10. Remove the gears and solenoids. You don't have to preserve the rotation of the gears, fortunately.
11. Do something about the sticky pads. I applied talcum with a cotton swab. Someone else used electrical tape. I don't know what's best or how long the talcum will work. The solenoids should operate freely without sticking. Be careful not to stretch the springs!

Put it back together in reverse order and you're all set! You can test operation without the side cover on, but you will need to put the front door on. Obviously, don't touch anything that could shock you.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip might be to run a dehumidifier or Air-conditioner in the area of the printer.  I had a Samsung printer that would always double-feed in the summer months when the humidity was high (>50%), but would work fine in dryer months.  Keeping your fresh dry paper in an air tight container before its put in the printer can also help as paper seems to stay "sticky" for some time after getting damp.

As was also said experiment with different paper types that same printer I had was also picky with the type/weight/grain of paper.  I eventually found that the a particular Domtar worked best and all my other printers were ok with it too.  Of course you should always "fan" the paper before putting it in and pay attention if there is static cling between the sheets.